# How do I insert a button in Javascript that can reach a function with onclick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have a javascript file that checks the server for results. If it fails to get the results after a certain number of attempts, I want to add a button to the page so the user can manually check for results. However, the button did not work when added. How do I fix it, do I need to do something to get the function in the scope of the button?

This is the code that adds the button:

```
$('.submitter').after("<span class='btn' onClick=delayDoing(0)>Check again</span>")
```

Which created the following button that does nothing:

```
<span class="btn" onclick="delayDoing(0)">Check again</span>
```

Below is the file of javascript. (I shortened it and removed some of the ERB stuff.)

```
 function delayDoing(attempts){
     setTimeout(function(){checkServer(attempts)}, 3000);
 }

 function checkServer(attempts){
     if ($('.results').css('opacity') === '0') { //no results           
         if(attempts < 4) {   
             // {code to check for results...}

             delayDoing(attempts+1);
         }
         else{
             $('.submitter').after("<span class='btn' onClick='delayDoing(0)'>Check again</span>")
         }
     }
}

jQuery(function() {
    delayDoing(0)
});
```

Comment: wrap the function name in quotes: onClick='delayDoing(0)'

Comment: @levi sorry, fixed. the button does nothing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var submit = $('.submitter'); //reference to the submitter button
var newButton = $("<span class='btn'>Check again</span>"); //in-memory button

submit.after( newButton ); //append the button to the DOM
newButton.click(function(){ delayDoing(0); }); //add a click event to the button and call for your function
```

Remember that javascript is compiled as it's loaded in the browser, since the element didn't exist on compile-time it won't trigger the click event, what you need to do is to append the element to the DOM AND add an event.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: There were some other issues with my code too, but I got it fixed in end. (The `$('.results').css('opacity') === '0'` wasn't the best condition to use.)